# AndEngine Drop shadow for sprite

Tags: java, android, andengine

I use AndEngine, And I need to drop shadow for sprite.
In sprite I use png texture. Can I draw shadow in code, or need draw it on Photoshop and impose under sprite?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really (!) need to create shadows dynamically then you could do something like this:

(removed)

**Update**

An easier way came into my mind:

- Create a `RenderTexture`.
- Render your `Sprite` to the `RenderTexture` several times with different scales and alpha values. i.e. scale=1, alpha=1 / scale=1.1, alpha=0.9 / scale=1.2, alpha=0.8 etc. Use as small steps as possible to achieve a smooth gradient.
- Create a `Sprite` using your `RenderTexture` and set its color to black (`Color.Black`).
- There you have your dynamic shadow ;)

Comment: @Taylor Swift hello star :)! Is there a reason for removing my more complex idea :)?

Comment: I didn't remove anything. Just improved your answer's format.

Comment: @TaylorSwift Oh sorry :) my fault. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create shadow as PNG file, attach it to your sprite and make it visible when needed. Can't create shadows dinamically in andEngine.

Comment: Of course, there are always ways ;) feel free to have a look at my ideas.